# How to use <Link> in onClick inside a button in order to pass a variable in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

***I am using Datagrid in Material-UI, I have created some buttons in order to edit the data on that specific row, I have the ID now I want to redirect /:id***

```
    const renderDetailsButton = (params) => {
  return (
    <strong>

        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          size="small"
          style={{ marginLeft: 16 }}
          onClick={() => {
              console.log(params.row.id);
              let id = params.row.id;
              <Link to=`/${id}`></Link>  //prints error
          }}
        >
          <EditIcon />
        </Button>
    </strong>
  );
};
```

Comment: You can remove button and use just Link instead, which should be  styled as your button

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do ? What is the error stack you get ? [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. You use a `Link` component. You can use the Material-UI Button component, and set the `component` prop to `Link`. In this case it will look like a button, but under the hood it will be a Link component:

   ```
   <Button component={Link} to={`/${id}`}>
       Redirect
   </Button>
   ```
2. You can redirect programatically in the onClick event handler. Assuming you use `React >=16.8` and function components, you can access the history object with the `useHistory` hook:

   ```
   import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
   import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";

   function MyComponent() {
       const history = useHistory();

       return (
           <Button onClick={() => history.push('/redirect/here')}>
               Redirect
           </Button>
       );
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is related to how you're passing data to the attributes in JSX/TSX in general. Instead of `to=<expression>` try wrapping the expression in brackets `{<expression>}`, it should look like this:

```js
// expression wrapped by {}
<Link to={`/${id}`}></Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to wrap id with curly brackets,

```
<Link to={`/${id}`}></Link>
```